# Arduino LED lighting up when signal is reading low on multimeter

Tags: sketch, arduino-pro-mini, signal-processing, prototype

My code is designed to play a tone when ever pin 3 is high on my Arduino. When I am examine the pins voltage with a multimeter it is always reading below 1 volt. When I examined the voltage off of a osiliscope it is reading the voltage pretty steady at 0.2 to 0.3.

**My multimeter reads at 0.26**

[image]:

**My code is:**

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
int input = digitalRead(3);
Serial.println(input);
if(input == 1){
  tone(A5,4000);
  }
}
```

**My board looks like:**
[image]
**The bottom of the board looks like:**
[image]

Comment: What pin are you measuring exactly? Pin 3 or pin A5? Is there a resistor in series with that LED? Is there a pull-up or pull-down resistor on pin 3? See [Switches Tutorial](http://gammon.com.au/switches).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left pin 3 floating. The multimeter will lower the voltage, resulting the the led lighting. Try enabling the pull-up resistor in pin 3 by adding `pinMode(3, INPUT_PULLUP)`.

PS you might want to add a resistor in series with that led, or it will burn out and/or damage pin 3 on the arduino.